# losing my mind - why doesn't my fetch re render (redux)

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk, rerender, optimistic-ui

In my project I have many users and many resources (and many user_resources/the join between users and resources).When I POST to user_resources I see it work on my rails backend (as in I see that instance posted) but in my react native front end I don't see it listed upon update. However, once the app is completely refresh (when I stop and restart the expo server), I finally see those items rendered. ANY IDEAS? I've been working on this forever now to no avail and my project is due tmrw, so any help is appreciated.

screen where I post to user_resources:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView,SafeAreaView,StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity,Button, NativeEventEmitter} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchResources,searchChanged} from '../actions';
import { addUserResource } from '../actions'
import {SearchBar} from 'react-native-elements';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

class ResourcesScreen extends React.Component {

  state = {
    search: ''
  }

  componentDidMount = () =>{
    this.props.fetchResources();
  }

  FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 0.5,
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "lightblue",
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  handlePress(item) {
    debugger
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/user_resources', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              Accept: 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              resource_id: item.id,
              user_id: this.props.users.id,
              name: item.name,
              description:item.description,
              link:item.link,
          
          })
      })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data2 => {
            console.log(data2)
              this.props.addUserResource(data2)
              console.log(this.props)
          })
  }

  header = () => {
  return <View>
  <Text style={styles.header}>Resources</Text>
      </View>
  }

  onSearchChange = text => {
    this.setState({search:text})
  }
 
  render(){
 
     return(
       <SafeAreaView>
       <SearchBar placeholderTextColor="white" placeholder="Enter resource name here" onChangeText={this.onSearchChange} value={this.state.search}/>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Add A New Resource',{topicId:this.props.route.params.topicId})} style={styles.buttonitem}>
<Text style={styles.text}>
    <MaterialIcons name="add-circle-outline" size={24} color="white"/>Add A New Resource 
</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>


      <FlatList  keyExtractor={(item)=> item.id.toString()} data={this.props.resourceName} ItemSeparatorComponent = { this.FlatListItemSeparator } renderItem={({item}) => {
        return <TouchableOpacity style={styles.material2}>
<Text onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Add A New Resource',{topicId:item.id})} style={styles.listitem}>{item.name}</Text>
<MaterialCommunityIcons name="bookmark-plus" size={50} color="#16a085" backgroundColor='black' onPress={()=>this.handlePress(item)}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
      }}
      ListHeaderComponent = {this.header}/>
      </SafeAreaView>
     )
   }
}

     const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        resourceName: state.resourceReducer.resources,
        users: state.userReducer,
        search:state.resourceReducer.searchTerm
      }
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
        fetchResources: () => dispatch(fetchResources()),
        addUserResource,
        searchChanged
      }
    }


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ResourcesScreen)
```

After this I head to the profile page where the user_resources SHOULD be displayed, but aren't

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView,StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {SearchBar} from 'react-native-elements';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';


class Profile extends React.Component{

      handleDelete = (id) => {
          debugger
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/user_resources/${id}`, {
            method: "DELETE",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": this.props.users.token
            }
        })
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then((delResource) => {
          console.log(delResource)
            this.props.deleteOneFood(delResource)
            console.log('deleted')
            this.forceUpdate()
        })

    }

  
render(){ 
    return(
           <View>
             {this.props.users.user_resources.map(singleResource=> {
               return <Text key={singleResource.id}>{singleResource.name}</Text>
             })}
       
          </View>
      
          )}
}

  

let deleteOneResource = (id) => {
    return {
        type: "DELETE_ONE_USER_RESOURCE",
        payload: id
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    deleteOneResource
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    users: state.userReducer,
  }
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Profile)
```

I had a flatlist before but thought that may be causing the issues so rendered it another way, still no luck. I tried forceUpdates as well, still no luck. I'm not sure if the issue is coming from my reducer:

```
let userInitialState = {
  id: 0,
  username: "",
  name: '',
  category: '',
  token: "",
  user_resources:[],
}

let userReducer = (state = userInitialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case "ADD_USERS":
      let singleNestedObject = { 
        ...action.users.user, 
        token: action.users.token
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        username: action.users.user.username,
        token: action.users.token,
        id: action.users.user.id,
        name: action.users.user.name,
        category: action.users.user.category,
        user_resources: action.users.user.user_resources
      }
      case "ADD_ONE_USER_RESOURCE":
        let copyOfResources = [...state.user_resources, action.userResources]
      return {
        ...state, 
        user_resources: copyOfResources
        }
      default: 
        return state
    }
  }
```

and it's action

```
export const addUserResource = (resourceInfo) => {
  return {
    type: "ADD_ONE_USER_RESOURCE",
    userResources: resourceInfo
  }
}
```

Please help me find the issue here, I'm losing it.

Comment: it should be  `resourceName: state.user_resources` instead of  `resourceName: state.resourceReducer.resources` in your `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: my issue isn't there - that screen is working fine it's where I'm rendering all resources. It's the screen where I try to render user_resources that doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(state)` in your `mapStateToProps` to see what value it contains? I suspect there can't be `user_reducer` or `resourceReducer` inside the state.

Comment: they're both there! but the props don't seem to update upon my post request :/

Comment: use [Expo](https://snack.expo.io/) and copy-paste your code so that it could be possible to see what's is going on?

Comment: sure one sec - the issue seems to be that when I post the new info to the reducer it isn't saved so problem must be there (copyOfResources comes back undefined)

Comment: it doesn't seem to ever hit the case of "ADD_ONE_USER_RESOURCE" but I'm not sure why